# How do I /tellraw the location of an arrow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm pretty new to NBT tags so there's a good chance this is a simple mistake, but I'm trying to tell the nearest player the XYZ location of an arrow that has hit the ground, currently I've got this running in a repeating command block:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:arrow , nbt={inGround:1b}] run tellraw @p {"nbt" : "" , "entity" : "@e[type=minecraft:arrow , nbt=inGround:1b]"}
```

This just prints a blank message at me.
It would be good if after this prints a second command block then kills that arrow but I don't even know where to begin with that.

Also, if anyone has any good resources on this topic, I would greatly appreciate it, there is very little good documentation that I've found.

I'm using Minecraft JE 1.16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problems:

- NBT should be surrounded in `{}`s. You did this in the first part with `/execute as`, but this needs also to be the same with the target selector in JSON text of the `/tellraw`.
  `nbt=inGround:1b` → `nbt={inGround:1b}`
- You haven't specified an NBT path to find the arrow's position. Use the JSON argument `{"nbt":"Pos[0]"}`. `Pos[0]` for X, `Pos[1]` for Y, and `Pos[2]` for Z.
  `Pos` is an array of three numbers representing entity position.

Fixed command (for X position):

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:arrow , nbt={inGround:1b}] run tellraw @p [{"nbt":"Pos[0]","entity":"@e[type=minecraft:arrow,nbt={inGround:1b}]"}]
```

## Suggestions

You don't need to use `/execute` to switch the executing entity to the arrow. Running the `/tellraw` from the command block will do just fine.

Command with suggestions applied:

```
tellraw @p [{"nbt":"Pos[0]","entity":"@e[type=minecraft:arrow,nbt={inGround:1b},limit=1]"}]
```

## Resources

Your one stop go-to resource for all your Minecraft commands needs is the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Wiki). The MC Wiki includes lots of documentation on how raw JSON text format works, with useful information on commands, and technical info on how they work. I used [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format) page as resource to compile this answer for you.